# How do you print two places exactly using zero-pad flag in a print statement

Tags: java, printf

if wanted to make a this method print using zero pad how do you do so

```
int month, day;

public void  printNumeric()
{
  System.out.printf("month +"/" +day +" \n");
  // i would like the month if it is 5 to be 05 same thing with the day
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int month, day;

public void  printNumeric()
{
  System.out.printf("%02d/%02d\n", month, day);
  // i would like the month if it is 5 to be 05 same thing with the day
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) or [String.format](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
String.format("%02d", somenumber)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<19; i++)
   System.out.format("i: %02d\n", i);
```